# My INSERT statement not working both in my php script and in phpmyadmin sql interface

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have been developing a website on localhost with xampp and everything worked perfect. so i moved to a web host for the first time. I have edited my connection string to fit the web server and it connects fine but when i tried testing the registration page i designed it doesn't insert data into the database. I tried a simple insert statement on a separate script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <?php
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "my_db_user_name", "my_db_password");
    $db = mysql_select_db("my_db_name");

    $query1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users firstname VALUES 'Patrick'",$conn);
    if($query1) {
        echo "Yes";
    } else {
        echo "didn't work";
    }
    echo mysql_error($query1);
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It returned the **didn't work** and didn't insert anything neither did it `echo` any error. But when i tried a select statement and `echo` the result of the query it worked so its safe to say my connection is valid.
I also went to my `cpanel` `phpmyadmin` interface and tried the same insert statement it didn't work but returned:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`firstname` VALUES 'Patrick'' at line 1.

I tried with and without back ticks the same thing. but i can select query.

Comment: Use the correct syntax:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html.

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard - seemingly nor is PDO by default (where it emulates prepared statements for MySQL) in the same edge case.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the correct syntax for the insert.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)
```

Example from w3schools:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to look like this

```
INSERT INTO (columns) VALUES (values)
```

So you will get

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('Patrick');
```

Answer (score -2):

Dude... one second google, and you would have your answer.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Also, the error says there is a SYNTAX ERROR. It is so difficult to understand? Why you don't simply check your syntax?

```
INSERT INTO users (firstname) VALUES ('Patrick')
```